# Why is 'b' being added to my Django app's varchar data after upgrading to Django 4.2?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am migrating an application from Django1.11/Python2.7/Postgres9.2 to Django4.2/Python3.11/Postgres14.3 (FYI I am also migrating the data from postgres 9 to 14). I am running into an issue where I call a form where the varchar data that is displayed in my app gets a "b'" and "'" appended to the data displayed by the form. Example (John is now 'bJohn') and modifies the data in the postgres database by adding the "b'" and "'" to the data. I have tried to clean the data, removed migrations, dropped the database, etc.

FYI when I type() the fields everything returns as type 'str', even after the b' is added to the data.

Here is my Model

```
class User(TimeStampedModel):
number = models.CharField(max_length=6, primary_key=True, verbose_name="Number")
moniker = models.CharField(max_length=32)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
full_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
department = models.CharField(max_length=32)
location = models.CharField(max_length=32)
employee_type = models.CharField(max_length=32)
title = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
mail = models.EmailField(max_length=32)
```

Here is my form

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['number', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'department',
              'location', 'employee_type', ]
    labels = {
        'number': _('Number'),
        'first_name': _('First Name'),
        'last_name': _('Last Name'),
        'mail': _('E-Mail Address'),
    }
```

Here how I call the form in my template.

```
{% block mainblock %}
<h1>System</h1>
<p>Please select from the options below.</p>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#uinfo">User Info</a></li>
        
    <div id="uinfo">
        <p>Your current user info:</p>

        <table id="usertable">
            {% for field in userformset %}

                <tr>
                    <td>{{ field.label }}</td>
                    <td>{{ field.value }}</td>
                </tr>

            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Here is how I call the from in my views

```
def index(request):
current_user = User.objects.get(number=request.user.username)
userform = UserForm(instance=current_user)

return render(request, 'includes/usermenu.html',
              {"userformset": userform, }, )
```

In my older version of django/python/postgres system data is displayed correctly when I call the form. In the upgraded version I get [image]
for all returned varchar data.

This is the what I get in the older when using the older versions. [image]

what is more interesting is the table in my postgres database also gets updated. The initial value for employee type in postgres is Employee but I call any data from the table with a model form the data is update to b'Employee'.

I have tried cleaned_data, strip(), [2:-1], etc, etc.

Postgres and Django are both encoded to utf-8 I don't know where to look or how to fix this issue, or if this is even an issue. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: `b'Employee'` means you have a `bytes` object instead of a `str` object.   If you do `b'Employee'.decode('utf-8')` you'll get `'Employee'` (i.e. a `str`).

Comment: `Python2.7` --> `Python3.11`. One of the if not the biggest change from Python 2  to 3 was string handling. See [Python 2 to 3](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) *Text versus binary data* for  starters. Short version `str` is not the same thing in Python 2 vs 3. Bottom line this is how strings are represented in Django under Python 3.

Comment: Adrian, Thank you the link you sent was great. I am still having trouble following what I need to do. I have already attempt to use the .decode() function which does remove the b' when printed to the terminal. The issue is the from creation because of what is explained in the link you provided. How do I modify the form to remove the b' from the string when rendering on the webpage? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I may not have describe my issue clearly but the answer to this issue was to create a filter.py file in the templatetags folder in my django instance. Hopefully this helps someone else.

filter.py

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()



@register.filter
def remove_prefix_and_suffix(value):
    print(value)
    if isinstance(value, str) and value.startswith("b") and value.endswith("'"):
        return value[2:-1]
    return value
```

In my template form.html I added the following in its respected location with the custom filter for field.value| remove_prefix_and_suffix.

```
{% load filter %}

        <div id="uinfo">
        <p>Your current user info:</p>

        <table id="usertable">
            {% for field in userformset %}

                <tr>
                    <td>{{ field.label }}</td>
                    <td>{{ field.value| remove_prefix_and_suffix }}</td>
                </tr>

            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
```

This removed the "b'" and "'" from the text values. My legacy data in the postgres database still gets update to add a "b'" and "'" when I pull a recored but from what I read that could just be a product of moving from python3.11 from python2.7.